# How to insert Arabic characters into SQL database?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, insert, arabic

How can I insert Arabic characters into a SQL Server database? I tried to insert Arabic data into a table and the Arabic characters in the insert script were inserted as `'??????'` in the table.

I tried to directly paste the data into the table through SQL Server Management Studio and the Arabic characters was successfully and accurately inserted.

I looked around for resolutions for this problems and some threads suggested changing the datatype to `nvarchar` instead of `varchar`. I tried this as well but without any luck.

How can we insert Arabic characters into SQL Server database?

Comment: How do you know it didn't work?  Perhaps your query program can't print Unicode characters.  What program is showing the "????"?  How do you know it can show Unicode properly?

Comment: In SQL management studio, when i query out the row then it displays as '????' and the same reflects in my program.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

For the field to be able to store unicode characters, you have to use the type `nvarchar` (or other similar like `ntext`, `nchar`).

To insert the unicode characters in the database you have to send the text as unicode by using a parameter type like `nvarchar` / `SqlDbType.NVarChar`.

(For completeness: if you are creating SQL dynamically (against common advice), you put an N before a string literal to make it unicode. For example: `insert into table (name) values (N'Pavan')`.)

Comment: +1 for the example. Thanks Guffa. There was another thread which suggested to prefix 'N'. But, I was not quite sure where exactly to do it.

Comment: I have already used the type  `ntext` , but always show `????` when I'm trying to add Arabic characters

Answer (score 9):

I think the solution is to first set the field to `ntext`, then write `N` followed by the value. For example:

```
insert into eng(Name) values(N'حسن')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to load data directly into the database like me, I found a great way to do so by creating a table using Excel and then export as CSV. Then I used the database browser SQLite to import the data correctly into the SQL database. You can then adjust the table properties if needed. Hope this would help.

Comment: treat as string CHARVAR or TEXT