# WHERE statment doesn't work with arabic

Tags: php, mysqli

I've got a database contains some arabic data, It works when I select all data. But when I use WHERE statment, something = something, something like something. It doesn't work.
I've escaped the strings and I've tried to use N

```
$full = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE question='$question'";
```

And I've printed the syntax

```
SELECT * FROM arabic WHERE question='متي اصدرت هيئه الامم المتحده الاعلان العالمي لحقوق الانسان ؟'
```

But it doesn't work

## **Solved:**

I've done these steps: http://tympanus.net/codrops/2009/08/31/solving-php-mysql-utf-8-issues/

Comment: What is `N` in `question=N`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11081270/sql-update-doesnt-work-with-foreign-languages-arabic    And it didn't work without N also

Comment: Does it error, or not return anything?

Comment: Did you try `or die(mysqli_error($db));` to get any debug information.

Comment: "But it doesn't work" doesn't help, since it does not say anything about what the cause it. Please add the specific error message you get back from mysql if the query fails.

Comment: `if(!$fullQ) {
echo mysqli_error($conn);
echo $full;
}` And it doesn't print an error ,fullQ is the query

Answer (score 0):

I think it's an encoding problem..

Make sure that your connection is set to utf8 right after you make the connection and before your query by this line:

```
mysqli_set_charset($con,"utf8");
```

Comment: `mysqli_query($conn, "SET character_set_results=utf8");
mb_http_output('UTF-8'); 
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
mb_http_output('UTF-8');
mb_http_input('UTF-8');
mb_language('uni');
mb_regex_encoding('UTF-8');
ob_start('mb_output_handler');
mb_language('uni'); 
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
mysqli_query($conn, "set names 'utf8'");
mysqli_set_charset($conn, "utf8");  `   Nothing more to do

Comment: The problem is your query content is really not equal to content in database because of encoding.  Is your file encoding utf8?  and your sql table too?

Comment: I think if it is not it wouldn't print all data without where

Comment: try to run this query:
SELECT * FROM arabic WHERE question like '%ا%'

Comment: Worked, So what I should do to make it work with inserted data?

Comment: Ok that means that your problem is not because it's arabic.. it's just your query didn't find any rows that match your statement.. What you've tried here is searching questions that have "ا" letter in them..

Comment: But, The value which I inputed is copied from the database I haven't even wrote it

Comment: ok it happened to me once.. try to write it and not copy it. and try to add % before and after..

SELECT * FROM arabic WHERE question='%متي اصدرت هيئه الامم المتحده الاعلان العالمي لحقوق الانسان ؟%'

Comment: Ok, Now I've tried to search for "م" it printed only to values, And there are more in the database. Also it printed it for me like this س1 ماذ&# and س9 بم ر& and these aren't arabic by anyway I've tried to put `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');` and `echo "<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html;charset=UTF-8'>";` also nothing and when I tried to search for متي it didn't print anthing and I've tried this `SELECT * FROM arabic WHERE question='%متي اصدرت هيئه الامم المتحده الاعلان العالمي لحقوق الانسان ؟%'` it printed nothing.

Comment: Where did print it like this? in browser or on log?

Comment: i still think there is something with arabic question because it works perfectly with english data with the same code

Comment: It happened to me once, and the problem was spaces between words.. they looked like space but it was different character so the query didn't match them. I Think that is your problem.. try to edit the text in database and write it again(not copy) then write in query and do it.

Comment: Do you mean to write them without spaces?

Comment: No, but maybe that a good direction to start check with.. In the previous comment I meant to write the text(in DB) again so if there were any characters that looks like space but it's not, you will replace them with real spaces.

Comment: I've tried it with one value to check and it didn't work

Comment: Then I'm sorry.. I recommend to build a little new script with new db and try there.. and be careful with every line you add in your script. I'm sure it's a little thing that make this problem.

Answer (score 0):

***Create database/table with 'utf8_general_ci' Collection.***

**Database Records:**

```
id |    name    
1  |    الترجمة
2  |    دينار
```

**PHP script:**

```
$conn=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','');
mysqli_select_db($conn,'test_data');
mysqli_query($conn,"set names utf8");

$sql="select * from employee where name='الترجمة'";
$fire=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($fire)){
    print_r($row);
}
```

Comment: sorry, din't get you.
please explain.

Comment: Database's and table's collection are already with utf8_general_ci

Comment: had you try this " mysqli_query($conn,"set names utf8");"  in php script.