# How to insert unicode (arabic) characters into SQL Server database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

I want to insert Unicode letters I have already tried changing the data types to `nvarchar(max)` and my select statement is

```
string str = "insert into Table1( (N'title), datee, post, cat, imageurl) values  ('" + TextBox1.Text + "','" + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() + "','" + TextBox2.Text + "','" + DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text + "','" + path+"')";`
```

Comment: Just a tip: Use parameterized queries.

Comment: @JanesAbouChleih can show me

Comment: Related Question :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1350968/how-to-insert-unicode-text-to-sql-server-from-query-window

Comment: Check the following post. It has your answer.

[How to insert arabic characters into sql database?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2881682/how-to-insert-arabic-characters-into-sql-database

Comment: @user2351986 I don't know which driver you use to access the database.
But mostly it's something like:
`SQLParameter myParam = new SQLParameter();
myParam.DBType = DBType.VARCHAR;
myParam.Value = xyz;
myCommand.Parameter.Add(myParam);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should **always** use parametrized queries to avoid SQL injection attacks. Parameters also give you the ability to explicitly define what **data types** and which length you want. Furthermore, by using parameters, you don't need to fiddle with lots of single and double quotes and so forth - the code becomes much cleaner and easier to read - and you avoid a lot of errors, too!

Try code something like this:

```
// define your INSERT statement with PARAMETERS
string insertStmt = "INSERT INTO dbo.Table1(title, datee, post, cat, imageurl) " +
                    "VALUES(@title, @datee, @post, @cat, @imageurl)";

// define connection and command
using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(yourConnectionStringHere))
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(insertStmt, conn))
{
     // define parameters and set their values
     cmd.Parameters.Add("@title", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100).Value = TextBox1.Text.Trim();
     cmd.Parameters.Add("@datee", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Now;
     cmd.Parameters.Add("@post", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100).Value = TextBox2.Text.Trim();
     cmd.Parameters.Add("@cat", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100).Value = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text.Trim();
     cmd.Parameters.Add("@imageurl", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 250).Value = path;

     // open connection, execute query, close connection
     conn.Open();
     int rowsInserted = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
     conn.Close();
}
```