# Insert arabic words in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a problem when I try to insert arabic text as sql `variable` in sql server 2008 , inserts data like this value `????` .How to solve this?

This is my query

```
insert into tests values(N''+@name)
```

The result shows like this:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: This might help you: http://www.sqlerudition.com/how-to-store-non-english-unicode-characters-hindi-czech-arabic-etc-in-sql-server/

Comment: Your column data types need to also be unicode.

Comment: What is the data type of your col? varchar?

Comment: my data type is nvarchar.

Comment: KinchitDalwani that link is working with strings like 'محسن' but i have variable @name.

Comment: @anshadali see my updates

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to insert arabic characters into sql database?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2881682/how-to-insert-arabic-characters-into-sql-database)

Comment: okay.let me check this link.thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use unicode datatypes for your data storage and begin your strings with N literal like this:

```
declare @t table(col Nvarchar(100)); 
insert @t (col) values (N'your text');
```

Or use the appropriate COLLATION with non-unicode data types but pass your values as unicode ones (with N) because your server/database collation seems to be different from arabic

Comment: I only pass variable @name from my c# code to the stored procedure.How to use N' for the variable @name?

Comment: define your c# parameter as unicode one; check your procedure parameter type as well

Comment: Finally the Issue solved using collation on database.@sepupic suggested me above for this method.Thank you @sepupic. I used this link http://www.serverintellect.com/support/sqlserver/change-database-collation. Thank you all for helping me.

Answer (score 4):

Try this and you will see what `Data Type` you shoule use :

```
DECLARE @V1 VARCHAR(50) = 'فيلم';
DECLARE @V2 NVARCHAR(50) = N'فيلم'

SELECT @V1 Varchar_Col, @V2 NVarchar_Col
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/RAQQ93212)

Update:

Try to use `SqlDbType.NVarChar` when you pass your `Parameter`.

and you can also try with :

```
INSERT INTO tests (ID_Number) VALUES (@name)
```

Comment: Any option to use N' in the variable @name?